# PHP Update Table Error - PDO

Tags: php, pdo

```
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $ctname = $_POST['ctname'];
    $id = $_POST['ctid'];
    $checktopic = $db->prepare("SELECT ct_name FROM topics WHERE ct_name = :ctname");
    $checktopic->bindParam(':ctname', $ctname);
    $checktopic->execute();

   //if topic exists
    if ($checktopic->rowCount() > 0) {
        $topicExistError = 'The topic already exists, please choose a different name';
    }

    //if topic is empty
    if (empty($ctname)) {
        $valid = false;
        $topicNameError = 'Please enter topic name';
    }

    else {
        $sql = "UPDATE `db`.`topics` SET  `ct_name` = ? WHERE `topics`.`id` = ?";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($ctname, $id));
        header ('topics.php');
    }
}
```

I have done a simple edit form to change the name of a topic. If the topic is empty it displays an error. However, when I try to change the name of a topic it seems to ignore my update statement and just goes straight to the header redirect.

There are no errors displayed and the SQL syntax has been tested and works according to my database. Any suggestions, thanks?

Comment: Is your PDO object `$db` setup to throw exceptions? By default it errors silently.  Do `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and comment out the `header()` call to debug any problems the statement may have caused.  Syntactically it looks ok, but there could be DB permissions problems or many other things.

Comment: For consistency, I would recommend using named parameters in the UPDATE just like you did in the SELECT. You can pass them as an associative array if you want to avoid calls to `bindParam()`.  `execute(array(':ct:name' => $ctname, ':id' => $id))` and replace the `?` in the statement.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have included the setup to throw exceptions and there is nothing displayed, so not sure why the update isn't working . I will make the amendments to make my code more consistent

Comment: Have you debugged the values returned by `rowCount()` and the value of `$id`? An update matching no rows by `$id` would just pass on.

Comment: update `db', is that right? or should it be ? "UPDATE topics SET ct_name = ? WHERE id = ?"

Comment: I have run the exact UPDATE statement in my code, replacing the question marks within phpMyAdmin and it works

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - The value of id returns correctly as it's shown above my textbox to edit the topic name.

Comment: @StackMeUp123 I should've asked earlier -  do you have display_errors enabled? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top, because an exception thrown wouldn't be visible without it, especially if you then redirect away.  So remove the `header()` if not already done and make sure errors are displaying.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski my error reporting on my phpinfo() shows "error_reporting  32767" - is that correct?

Comment: @StackMeUp123 Yes, that would be the value of the E_ALL constant. Enable display_errors and you should be all set.